# OpenXML Spreadsheet corrupted in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, openxml

I am working with OpenXML (2.5) to create a customized spreadsheet.  On the VM I am using, I only have Open Office in which the OpenXML spreadsheet was working fine (with custom formatting and everything).  However, when moving the file to a machine with Microsoft Office, each version of the file failed to open due to corrupted data. I took out all the customization and still had a corrupted result (which still worked in Open Office).

This is the code I have for a bare bones spreadsheet file, which, again, works in Open Office but is seen as corrupt in Excel.

```
public string CreateGrid()
{
    var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
    var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    var workbookpart = document.AddWorkbookPart();

    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
    document.Close();
    return path;
}
```

The error I get is 'An invalid character was found in the text content.'
Line: 1
Column: 1
File Offset: 0
As you can see in the code, I'm not adding any text as of yet, it I'm fairly certain it isn't illegal characters.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload somewhere the XLSX file that reproduces your issue? I'll take a look at it and let you know what problem it has.

Comment: I was able to figure out both the original issue and why it was failing when it was only a workbook.  Excel expects all the elements to be there (workbook, worksheet and content).  If there's only a workbook, it fails the check.  The original problem I had (with the data in it) was that I wasn't creating a new row on each iteration.  Essentially I was creating a single row with multiple rows inside of it.  Noob mistake on may part -_-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem.  Firstly, with the code I have above, Excel expects a fully formatted file when using OpenXML. That means just having a file with a workbook won't suffice, it has to have the workbook, worksheets and at least 1 sheet for it to open properly.  The other problem I had (where the data would not display in Excel), was because as I was traversing down rows, I was not creating a new row each time. For anyone attempting the same thing I was, the code should look like this:

```
foreach (var temp in tempList)
{
    if (cellIdex == 12)
    {
        cellIdex = 0;
        rowIdex = rowIdex + 1;
        row = new Row { RowIndex = rowIdex };
        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
     }
     cell = CreateTextCell(ColumnLetter(cellIdex), rowIdex, tempToString(), 3);
     row.AppendChild(cell);
     cellIdex = cellIdex + 1;
}
```

The most important part to note is the "row = new Row{RowIndex = rowIdex};".  Might seem simple but caused me a lot of headache.